# How to dynamically push an radio button in to array

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I am using this sort of code in the fiddle given below.

http://jsfiddle.net/darrenarbell/4HTEr/

In that fiddle instead of 2 i want a `radio button` or `checkbox`
How can i do that. Hope you understand my question.

Thanks and Regards
Srinivas

Comment: Simply concatenate where you want like after .push("<input type=\"radio\" name=\"XYZ\"/>")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API docs: [columns.encoded](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#columnsencoded%20booleandefault)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4HTEr/248/

Essential part:

```
columns.push({
        field: entryIndex,
        title: "Column " + i,
        encoded: false
    });
```

See `encode: false` in column description. And, of course, while preparing data:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var entryArray = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        entryArray.push("<input type=\"checkbox\" />");
   }
    rows.push(kendo.observable({
        entries: entryArray
    }));
}
```

checkboxes HTML code pushed instead of "2"